# YouTube IFrame Player API Thumbnails not showing

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, youtube

I'm having this code that create the iframe for my youtube video
but I'm not so sure how to show the thumbnail, as for now it's just
show a black box and after I click it the video start playing.

I tried player.cueVideoById('eJSik6ejkr0',0,'highres') but still none.

any idea what could I do to make the thumbnail visible?

thanks

```js
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '475',
          width: '100%',
          videoId: 'eJSik6ejkr0',
    playerVars: { 'rel': 0, 'modestbranding': 1, 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0 },
          events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
```

Comment: When I use your snippet inside the answer below I get `This contains content from VEVO. It is restricted from playback on certain sites`. This explains why you don't get a thumb nail.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example given in the [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en) and correctly shows a thumbnail. However, some content providers will limit playblack to certain sites and therefore you may get a thumbnail. Using your videoId i get a black box with this message in the middle: `This contains content from VEVO. It is restricted from playback on certain sites`

```html
< !DOCTYPE html>
  < html>
    < body>
      <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
      < div id="player">
        < /div>

          <script>
            / /
            2.This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
            var tag = document.createElement('script');

            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

             // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
             //    after the API code downloads.
            var player;

            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
              player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '390',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                events: {
                  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
              });
            }

             // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
            function onPlayerReady(event) {
              event.target.playVideo();
            }

             // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
             //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
             //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
            var done = false;

            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
              if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                done = true;
              }
            }

            function stopVideo() {
                player.stopVideo();
              } < /script>
  </body >
              < /html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I managed it...

the vevo was just an example (bad one)... I had 5 videos (main one and 4 small videos) on the page and I used the pausedVideo method on all 4 small vids right after the main video was running so it made them all goes "black".

now it's fine, thanks for the help!